# How to set preselected options into a multiple select tag according to a php array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, select

I have made a multiple select tag and I would like some of its options to be selected according to given PHP array $attr

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="isattr[]" id="editAttr">
<?php         
    while($attrresult = mysqli_fetch_array($attrfetch)) {
        echo  "<option>".$attrresult[attr_title]."</option>";
     }
?>
</select>
```

So if the `select` tag has the options "Manager" "Programmer" "Teacher" and `$attr` contains the values "Manager" and "Programmer", these options should be preselected.

Comment: I don't see `$attr` anywhere in the above code. Where is that coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `in_array()` to check if the value is in the `$attr` array, and apply the selected property to the element based on that :

```
<select multiple = "multiple" name = "isattr[]" id = "editAttr" >
<?php

    $attr = array("Manager", "Programmer");

    while ($attrresult = mysqli_fetch_array($attrfetch)) {

        $selected = in_array( $attrresult[attr_title], $attr ) ? ' selected' : '';

        echo "<option".$selected.">".$attrresult[attr_title]."</option>";

    } 
?> 
< /select>
```

Comment: Great. Glad that you knew where `$attr` was coming from.